# req.body retornando undefined quando utilizo consign na aplicação

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou me familizariando com o express, então criei um Form simples com dois campos, tenho tb um arquivo JS onde recebo os dados do form e os envio através do `xmlHttpRequest` e no lado do servidor, estou usando consign para gerenciar minhas rotas, o problema, é que sempre que adiciono ele, o retorno do método que recebe o post do form no lado do server retorna sempre undefined.

formulário

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" id='form'>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

app.js (Onde capturo o form)

```
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const name = document.querySelector('#name');
  const password = document.querySelector('#password');

  const person = {
    name: name.value,
    password: password.value,
  };

  console.log(person); //imprime o que eu quero normalmente

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/person', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(person));
});
```

index.js (onde configuro o express)

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let consign = require('consign');

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

consign().include('routes').into(app);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('rodando');
});
```

Nesse aquivo acima, se eu tirar o `let consign`, a linha onde eu dou um include nele e adicionar um app.post para a rota /users eu consigo receber os dados normalmente.

Esse é o arquivo que está dentro de routes e que está retornando undefined:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  const person = app.route('/person');

  person.post((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Não há necessidade deste `value` em `req.body.value`

Comment: Você apenas terá acesso às key's name e password (req.body.name, req.body.password)

Comment: @CláudioHilário o meu req.body era undefined. Eu parei de usar o consign e passei a usar o express.Router() mesmo, acho que era algum conflito então....

Comment: @ValdeirPsr  o meu req.body era undefined. Eu parei de usar o consign e passei a usar o express.Router() mesmo, acho que era algum conflito então...